# Как реализовать перестраивание блоков

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

Я пытаюсь перестроить блоки, чтобы из такого, когда экран больше `500px`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Стало таким

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`html` структуру можно поменять, это не важно.

Нужно, чтобы при меньше `500px` лого было слева, большая картинка справа, картинки на одной линии, а меню следующим блоком. Можно ли это решить только на `flex`?

Я пытался использовать гриды, но не получилось.

Я хочу это сделать только на `CSS`, с помощью `JS` я могу это сделать, но я хочу разобраться как можно так перестраивать блоки

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

h3,
h2,
ul,
li,
body,
p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.container {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.header {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.header__nav {
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.header__ul {
  background: SteelBlue;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px
}

.header__img {
  max-width: 100px;
}

.header__img img {
  height: 100%;
}

.offer {
  padding: 5px;
}

.offer:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.offer:last-child {
  background-color: #85ef62;
}

.offer img {
  min-width: 170px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.main__title {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.offer__text {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.offer__title {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.offer__description {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  padding: 14px;
}

.mail {
  color: #05c8ff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .offer {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .offer img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 130px;
    margin-right: 0;
    min-width: auto;
  }
  .header__ul {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="section1">
  <div class='container'>
    <header class="header flex">
      <div class="header__img">
        <img src='https://picsum.photos/150/150'>
      </div>
      <nav class="header__nav flex">
        <img class="menu" src='https://picsum.photos/600/100'>
        <ul class="flex header__ul">
          <li>
            <a href='#Menu1'>Меню1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href='#Menu2'>Меню2</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href='#Menu3'>Меню3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href='#Menu4'>Меню4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <main class="main__content">
      <h2 class="main__title">Мы ищем</h2>
      <div class="offers">
        <div class='offer flex'>
          <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/200'>
          <div class="offer__text">
            <h3 class="offer__title">Заголовок1</h3>
            <p class="offer__description">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
              in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- .offer -->
        <div class='offer flex'>
          <img src='https://picsum.photos/200/200'>
          <div class="offer__text">
            <h3 class="offer__title">Заголовок1</h3>
            <p class="offer__description">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
              in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- .offer -->
      </div>
      <!-- .offers -->
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">
      <p>Управленцы TheBest, Москва</p>
      <p>
        <a class="mail" href='#mail'>hrthebest@gmail.com</a>
      </p>
      <p>999-999-999</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <!-- .container -->
</div>
<!-- .section -->
```

Comment: насколько помню - есть order в css, с флексами должен работать

Comment: @АлексДанилин я умею им пользоваться, пробовал, но у меня всё равно не получилось

Comment: @МихаилКамахин А что с гридами не получилось?

Comment: @Denis640Kb я их плохо знаю, поэтому я не смог понять, как мне перестроить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я не верно понял вопрос...

Вот решение на гридах

```css
.wrap {
  color: white;
  display: grid;
  /*определяем на сколько частей делиться родитель строкой ниже*/
  /*дочернему элементу задаем grid-area: logo; имя */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  /*А тут записывая имена дочерних элементов  задаем определяем их полжение 
  в родительском элементе */
  grid-template-areas: 
  "logo foto foto foto"
  "logo menu menu menu"
  ;
}

.logo {
  background: red;
  grid-area: logo;
}

.foto {
  background: green;
  grid-area: foto;
}

.menu {
  background: blue;
  grid-area: menu;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
.wrap {
  color: white;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "logo  foto foto foto"
  "menu  menu menu menu";
}

}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="logo">logo</div>
  <div class="foto">foto</div>
  <div class="menu">menu</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если `флексогриды` не принципиальны (а я их принципиально сам стараюсь не использовать и пока что никому не рекомендую), то вот решение. Всё допотопно просто, и главное работать будет везде, даже на деревяшке

```css
.header {position: relative; width: 100%; height: 150px;}

.logo {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 150px; height: 150px; background: #16bcb8;}

.banner {float: right; width: calc(100% - 150px); height: 100px; background: #6b9aad;}

.nav {float: right; width: calc(100% - 150px); height: 50px; background: #4474c6;}

img {height: 100px; width: 100%;}

@media (max-width: 800px) {.banner,img {height: 150px;}.nav {width: 100%;}}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="banner"><img src="https://portaltele.com.ua/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/twitter.jpg"></div>
  <div class="nav"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.container {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.flex-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.menu {
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  margin-left: auto;
}
.header {
  position: relative;
}
.header__nav {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: calc(100% - 150px);
  margin-left: auto;
}
.header__ul {
  background: SteelBlue;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px
}
.header__img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 150px;
}
.header__img  img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .header__img {
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
  }
  .header__nav {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
      
          <header class="header flex flex-wrap">
            <div class="header__img">
              <img src='https://picsum.photos/150/150'>
            </div>
            <img class="menu" src='https://picsum.photos/600/100'>
            <nav class="header__nav">
              
              <ul class="flex header__ul">
                <li>
                  <a href='#Menu1'>Меню1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href='#Menu2'>Меню2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href='#Menu3'>Меню3</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href='#Menu4'>Меню4</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </header>
      
                
        </div>
```

Comment: Зря удалил [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1099434/Фон-квадратами-с-расстоянием-между-ними-и-градиентом#)